# Mule: Foreach looping on Jackson ArrayNode object

Tags: java, jackson, mule, mule-studio

I have a payload that's a JsonNode, which contains an ArrayNode. I would like to use this ArrayNode and iterate over its elements in a ForEach element. I set my ForEach collection variable as #[payload.get("MyArrayNode").getElements()], but I get an error that the object cannot be used by the ForEach component. I have also tried #[payload.get("MyArrayNode")] without success either.

Is there a way to iterate over Jackson objects or should I convert my payload to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IteratorUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/IteratorUtils.html) to create a List from the getElements Iterator:

```
#[org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils.toList(payload.get('MyArrayNode').elements)]
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked. Do you know where I can find information to answer such questions? The Mule docs don't seem to cover this sort of issues.

Comment: Not really, I "just know" Mule has the package included, and it's one option for iterator->list. I usually look at the Mule JavaDocs and/or source code to cover for missing documentation, or pick up things from blogs, etc.